# Countif's Date Range Across 2 Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, countif, date-range

I've tried Googling everything and have found how to use Countifs between 2 date ranges but I can't figure out how to do the same across 2 sheets.  This is the formula I used for just one sheet:

```
=countifs('2020'!E10:E680,">=1/1/2021",'2020'!E10:E680,"<=1/31/2021")
```

This is the formula I've tried between 2 sheets but I keep getting "formula parse error":

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(('2020'!E10:E681,'2021'!E10:E681,">=2/1/2021",'2020'!E10:E681,'2021'!E10:E681,"<=2/28/2021")))
```

I would love some assistance if it's possible.

Comment: Do two COUNTIFS and add them together.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using COUNTIFS in an incorrect way. If you will look into it, COUNTIFS() parameters should be in (range, criterion, range, criterion) format whereas in your formula, it became (range, range, criterion, range, range, criterion). You can try the formula below and see if it works for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS({'2020'!E10:E681,'2021'!E10:E681},">=2/1/2021",{'2020'!E10:E681,'2021'!E10:E681},"<=2/28/2021"))
```